# Issue in saving file from docker container to host

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using below command to save files generated from Docker container to host machine. But my files are not being saved after I exit the container. I tried different ways but none is working.

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)/sever-data/src:/data" test bash
```

Thank you

Comment: You are not giving enough information about your issue to answer your question. you can try the linux `sync` command in your container, or check permissions on your host, but it is hard to tell what your issue really is.

Comment: @Nathanael, thanks I tried sync in the container but its not working too

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following command to save container data to the host directory and its working perfectly fine.

```
 sudo docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/sever-data/src -w /sever-data/src
```